# How do you iterate through a mutable repeated Proto field in C++ using a range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

How do you you iterate through a mutable repeated Protocol Buffer field using a range-based for loop in C++?

Answer (score 26):

Use a reference:

```
for (MyProto &my_proto : *container->mutable_my_protos()) {…}
```

Comment: I don't understand the down votes, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Ah that * , thank you!  The VS error message did not at all suggest the for  was failing to compile because I had a pointer.